# Listing files from tar.gz and .vhd presents bad information

Tags: c#, class-library, sevenzipsharp

Listing files using sevenzipsharp from tar.gz and .vhd files presents bad information. There is thousand files but it presents only one with name represented as [no name]. Try listing http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz and see for your self. This works fine with sevenziplib library from http://sevenziplib.codeplex.com/. But sevenziplib doesn't do multipart archives well it always throws exception like file not found '.r13'. but archive have only part till .r12. Multipart archives works fine with sevenzipsharp

Comment: What is your question here?  To me this just looks like a bug report ... sent to the wrong place.

Comment: i'm looking for a workaround for this problem.